# Rails array syntax question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax

I'm in the console, looking at someone else's app.  I come across the following:

```
>> p.location
=> [#<Tag id: 2, name: "projects">]
```

Why do I see this result, which seems to be the object name, and how do I access the actual attribute name, "projects"?

```
>> p.location.name
=> "Tag"
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
p.location[0].name
## OR
p.location.first.name
```

p.location is an array of one element

Comment: @Veep, you are just new to Rails. Also, if this answered your question, feel free to mark it as answered to that future people might  find this to be a useful solution to their problem.